# Why is the stored value in each D flip flop reconnected to the input in a buffer register?

Tags: flipflop, buffer, register

[image: 4 bit register]

Like can one not just connect a single AND gate with the load and X input instead of complicating by reconnecting the output and using another OR gate? Will it be logically the same? or is it that I am missing out on something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the LOAD input.  That has to be high to allow new data to be loaded into the flip-flops.  When LOAD is low, it effectively loads the existing data into the flip-flop.  That was apparently the simplest way for the designers of this chip to have the flip flops keep their existing values when a clock edge is applied.